# How to set scroll top to bootstrap3 tab

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/1fus4o1q/

This is my working fiddle. At the end of the home tab "Go to top" link should goes to profile page.

**My HTML Code is:**

```
<a href="#profile" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile" class="go_to_top">Go to Top</a>
```

**Script:**

```
   $(' a.go_to_top').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');    

    });
```

If i click the link it goes to the profile tab. But it goes to bottom on the section. I needs to go to top. How can I acheive this?? Or any other way to reach.

Comment: have you tried `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').offset().top})` after `show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/vhvLnyxg/)?

```
$(' a.go_to_top').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]');
    $target.tab('show');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$target.offset().top})
});
```

Comment: is it possible set value "0" for top??

Comment: Thank you. I have changed to "$('html, body').scrollTop( 0 );" Now it is working.